# Word Copying, Pasting and Deleting Columns with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document with tables throughout.
I have a macro that I use to copy values from cells in certain columns and paste them into other columns. Then the macro deletes several columns from the table.

Generally I use bookmarks for the copying and pasting.

The Bookmarks are all cells in a specific column, except the header. 
So for example "Objectives" bookmark would span from row2 of column 2 of table5, until the end of column2. So if the user adds a row, that would also be included in the bookmark.

Here is an example below:

```
If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("ProposedOverallObj") = True Then
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Item("ProposedOverallObj").Select

Selection.Cut
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Objectives"
With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
    .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
    .ShowHidden = False
End With
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
End If

 Dim Table1 As Table
Set Table1 = ThisDocument.Tables(5)


If Table1.Columns.Count >= 5 Then
    With Table1
        .Columns(5).Delete
        .Columns(4).Delete
        .Columns(3).Delete
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "Not enough columns!"
End If
```

and it goes on like this for about 13 tables. The first few tables work fine, then i start running into a weird error where randomly the line of text above my table gets copied into the table header and then my "delete columns" code breaks and tells me that one of the columns has already been deleted. (it hasn't).

[image: Error Message]
[image: Object Has Been Deleted]

Is there a better way to do this? Might this be happening because I am using .Select? I know it can be sketchy. Would it be better to assign IDs to my column ranges rather than using bookmarks and select? if so, could you provide me with a small example code for using Dim on a range in a table (my range will always start on row2 and go to the end of the column)?

Comment: Hard to analyse without seeing how/where the bookmarks are defined... Is this "wrong text" originally part of a bookmark? One thing I'd try differently is to transfer data directly between bookmarks rather than using the clipboard, for example: `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Item("Objecttives").Range.FormattedText = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ProposedOverallObj").Range.FormattedText` Note that I'd use `Range` objects instead of writing it all out (think of `Range` like an invisible selection, except there can be multiple ranges in your code) and then you can use `Range.Delete`.

Comment: Note that it's not possible to bookmark or set table *columns* to a Range. But I'm not convinced that's the issue, here. How the code is working with tables and the interaction of bookmarks and tables is not clear enough to know what might be happening. We need steps to reproduce the problem...

Comment: @CindyMeister, thanks for that. I tried 
   ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Item("Objecttives").Range.FormattedText = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ProposedOverallObj").Range.FormattedText     but I got a vague "cannot copy content between these two ranges" message

Comment: As noted in comments above, we really, really need to know how the document is set up with these bookmarks. Without that information it's impossible to help you. You can use the [edit] link below the question to add information, FWIW it sounds as if one or more of the bookmarks contain table structures (entire cell, for example).

Comment: @CindyMeister, I've edited with a little more info about my bookmarks. I don't know exactly what you need to know about them beyond that, but let me know if it's not enough.

Comment: Thanks, the info that the bookmarks contain entire rows helps - and is why `FormattedText` doesn't work. The following should *not* use `ThisDocument` as it will always reference the document that contains the code. Use `ActiveDocument` instead: `Set Table1 = ThisDocument.Tables(5)`. Not sure if that will affect the problem, though...

Comment: Beyond that, I can only suggest putting a breakpoint just before where the problems start then use F8 to step through the code, always checking where the "action location" is. Then you can narrow down where the wrong text is getting copied, for example.